# How do I find the passphrase which encrypts my home directory?

Tags: linux, security, encryption, home, disk-encryption

Years ago I installed Ubuntu and encrypted my home directory.

I can still log in as normal, I know my password and I have access to my files.

Just now, installing Lubuntu on another machine, I saw this:

[image]

I don't remember writing down my passphrase for recovering my encrypted home directory when I set it up years ago.

So hypothetically I guess the disaster scenario is my root partition gets corrupted but not my home partition, or something like that, and I want to be able to recover my `/home` data.

I can log in and read my encrypted `/home` as normal right now. How do I find the recovery passphrase?

Comment: The dialog box tells you how to find the recovery passphrase, doesn’t it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about unix or linux, it's about failing to read the explicit instructions on screen that directly answers the question asked by providing the exact command line to run (`ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase`).

Comment: Sincerely, thank you for pointing out the obvious. I was very tired :-/

Answer (score 3):

With `ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase`

<sub>[On the off-chance that there's not something funny about this question, maybe there's a legitimate language barrier or some other issue,
 might as well make it an "official answer"]</sub>

---

Hints:

- You might want to make a backup of eCryptfs's important files too, in `/home/.ecryptfs/<user>/.ecryptfs/` especially the `wrapped-passphrase` file - if it gets damaged your home's really inaccessible even if you remember the passphrase.

  The `ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase` tool takes that file and your passphrase, and reveals the actual "random" encryption key.
- Your actual encrypted files are stored in `/home/.ecryptfs/<user>/.Private/`, but alone they're useless without the `wrapped-passphrase` file + passphrase.
- You should have a backup of any important files in your encrypted home, it's a lot easier than trying to recover from failing drives or overwritten encryption.

[[eCryptfs encrypted home - explanation - on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/850793/ecryptfs-encrypted-home-explanation/850814#850814)]